# Display button on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I am trying to display when button is click then another button will be display for this I try this but not working

```
<div class="rightdiv">
    <div id="BTNONE">
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="New Tab" OnClick="Button2_Click" style="display: none;" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" /><br />
    </div>    
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Button1").on('click', function () {
            $("#BTNONE").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your code is work. but i try using html.

```js
$(function () {
        $("#Button1").on('click', function () {
            $("#Button2").show();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rightdiv">
        <div id="BTNONE">
            <button type="button" ID="Button2" value="New Tab" style="display: none;" />
              Button 2
            </button>
            <button ID="Button1" value="Button" />Button 1</button>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#BTNONE` div is not hidden - it's the first `<button />` within it so, your 
selector is incorrect.

Also note that when using the `runat="server"` attribute on an ASP.Net control means that you cannot necessarily rely on the `ID` attribute being the same when the control is rendered on the client.

With that in mind, try this:

```
$("#BTNONE button:eq(1)").on('click', function () {
    $("#BTNONE button:eq(0)").show();
});
```

Comment: Will this code work if there is a postback happening? since Op also have a `OnClick="Button1_Click"` added to the asp `Button1`.

Comment: It depends on what that click handler is doing - it could be an AJAX request through an update panel.

Answer (score 1):

your hidden button id is`button2`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Button1").on('click', function () {
            $("#Button2").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function () {
        $("#Button1").on('click', function () {
            $("#Button2").show();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rightdiv">
        <div id="BTNONE">
            <button type="button" ID="Button2" value="New Tab" style="display: none;" />
              Button 2
            </button>
            <button ID="Button1" value="Button" />Button 1</button>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)